# Python Logging. Messages are with the same date

Tags: python, logging

I get log messages with the same date when I print them to the console (or logfile). But the time-out between messages is two seconds.  Here is my code

```
folder = "logs"
log_name = {}.log
file_name = os.path.join(folder, log_name)

date_format = "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S"
name_format = "[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] [%(filename)s:%(lineno)s] - %(message)s"

log = logging.getLogger('')
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
format = logging.Formatter(name_format, datetime.now().strftime(date_format))

console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
file_handler = handlers.RotatingFileHandler(filename=datetime.now().strftime(file_name.format(date_format)),
                                            maxBytes=(1048576*5),
                                            backupCount=7)
console_handler.setFormatter(format)
file_handler.setFormatter(format)

log.addHandler(console_handler)
log.addHandler(file_handler)


from time import sleep
log.info("1")
sleep(2)
log.info("2")
sleep(2)
log.info("3")
```

Here is output:

```
[2017-07-08_17:20:51] [INFO] [logs.py:112] - 1
[2017-07-08_17:20:51] [INFO] [logs.py:114] - 2
[2017-07-08_17:20:51] [INFO] [logs.py:116] - 3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have a look at the documentation of [`logging.Formatter(fmt=None, datefmt=None, style='%')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter). the second argument you need to pass is a `datefmt` (`"%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S"` in your case). the logger will do the `fmt.strftime(...)` for you.

you are passing a string that represents `datetime.now()` in this format. as this is a `str` (e.g. `'2017-07-08_17:20:51'`) the formatter does not complain but always prints *this* exact date: `'2017-07-08_17:20:51'.strftime(...)` will result in `'2017-07-08_17:20:51'` - there are no format specifiers to fill in.

what you should do is this:

```
fmt = logging.Formatter(name_format, date_format)
# instead of
# format = logging.Formatter(name_format, datetime.now().strftime(date_format))
```

(btw: [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) is a built-in; renamed your formatter to `fmt` such that the built-in is not overwritten).

Comment: Thank you very much